# Fill area with fixed size elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm creating an application to calculate how much solar panels would fit on a specific roof.

Users can input the dimensions of their roof.
We only have on size of solar panels available.

I thought a canvas was the way to go but I don't seem to find the information I need..

**Requirements**

1) Based on the input of the user the canvas should be resized (currently I have a rectangle inside the canvas changing to this size)

2) User should be able to create (and size) objects to put on the roof (chimney, window,..)

3) Based on the open space left solar panels (rectangles) should be automaticly drawn on the canvas

**Dimensions and limitations**

- 1px = 2cm
- Spacing to edge of roof and object is 7px (14cm)
- Solar panel is 169 cm height and 102 cm width

I've checked out the fabric.js library but can't seem to find something close to what I need.

The js I got so far to draw the canvas:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("c");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var width=50;
var height=35;
var $width=document.getElementById('width');
var $height=document.getElementById('height');

var paneelWidth=101;
var peneelHeight=170;

$width.value=width;
$height.value=height;

draw();

$width.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    width=this.value/2;
    draw();
}, false);

$height.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    height=this.value/2;
    draw();
}, false);


function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.fillRect(10,10,width,height)
}
```

**Update**

The canvas now does resize in a dynamic way based on user input.

I also found the function createPattern(), which is bringing me closer to the solution.

I've added this code to generate a pattern of solar panels in the canvas:

```
function placepanels(direction) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var img = document.getElementById("paneel");
  var pat = ctx.createPattern(img, direction);

  var w2 = canvas.width - 7;
  var h2 = canvas.height - 7;

  ctx.rect(7, 7, w2, h2);
  ctx.fillStyle = pat;
  ctx.fill();
}
```

The -7 on width and height is beacause I need 14cm space on each size of the canvas. Hence why I offset the rectangle containing the pattern 7px from left and top. Currently not able to achieve this on right and bottom side.

**Current issue**

The result I'm getting is not looking correct, it seems like the pattern repeats wrong (to much repeats) or it's not getting the proper size of the image to repeat.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8e05ghqy/3/

Comment: This is pretty complex geometry stuff, and sort of OT right now.

Comment: @Chris G not complex at all...

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for?, it's not clear. Looks like you want us to do it.

Comment: Hi @MarioE the answer I'm looking for is more of a hint in the right direction. Is fabric.js something that'll be able to help me with this? For now I'm totally new to canvas part, I'm not even able to find how to adapt the canvas size to the user input.

Comment: @Maarten I suggest that you learn about canvas first before using any canvas library.

Comment: @Maarten See MDN's canvas guides and tutorials https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API#Guides_and_tutorials

Comment: You need to subtract 14 from both width and height, then reduce it further until it's a multiple of the dimensions of one panel: https://jsfiddle.net/8e05ghqy/4/

Answer (score 0):

As for the canvas resize, this function would do it:

```
changeCanvasSize = function( width, height ) {
    $('canvas').width(width)
    $('canvas').height(height)
}
```

Example of usage: `changeCanvasSize(450,250)` would change the canvas size to 450px of width and 250px of height.
I am just resizing the HTML `<canvas>` element `.width( value )` and `.height( value )` works for any HTML element.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @MarioE ! I've been able to get few steps closer to the result. I've updated the opening post and fiddle.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment.